# How can I define constants in a Template Tookit template in a Catalyst app?

Tags: perl, constants, catalyst, template-toolkit

I want to use a constant in my TT template. In [HTML::Mason](http://search.cpan.org/dist/HTML-Mason) (my previous templating engine of choice) I could do:

```
<%once>
use MyApp::Constants qw(CONSTANT);
</%once>
```

How can I do this in [Template Toolkit](http://www.template-toolkit.org)? As mentioned in the title this is a [Catalyst](http://www.catalystframework.org) app so I was thinking I could put the constants in the stash but that seems a bit awkward.

--edit

Sorry - I should have mentioned I want to use my own constants - exported from MyApp::Constants, without duplication.

Comment: OK, I found it difficult in selecting an answer - but I chose fiedo's as it is closest to my eventual solution. I will inject my constants into $c->stash so they can be used by the templates - similar to passing them in the Template constructor. The great thing with TT is it does not use sigils so if they are a subroutine or a scalar they are referenced the same way

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your TT configuration, you can use the [VARIABLES](http://template-toolkit.org/docs/manual/Config.html#section_VARIABLES) option to pass a list of values that will be passed to every template when it's processed. Using some symbol table trickery, you can suck out all your constants into the config:

```
use MyApp::Constants;
use Template;


my $tt;     # template object
{ 
    no strict 'refs';
    $tt = Template->new( { 
        VARIABLES => { map { $_ => &{ 'MyApp::Constants::' . $_ } } 
                       grep { defined &{ 'MyApp::Constants::' . $_ } }
                       keys %MyApp::Constants::
                     }
        }
    )
}
```

This looks at all the symbols in the package `MyApp::Constants`, checks if they are defined as subroutines (this is what `constant.pm` does under the hood) and then uses `map` to provide a hashref of them to TT.

Comment: You could also use the `CONSTANTS` option instead of the `VARIABLES` option.

Answer (score 2):

Several possibilities.
Just define some variables:

```
[% users = {
     tom   => 'Thomas',
     dick  => 'Richard',
     larry => 'Lawrence',
   }
%]

[% FOREACH u IN users %]
   * [% u.key %] : [% u.value %]
[% END %]
```

Use the global variable:

```
[% global.version=1.234 %]

This is Version [% global.version %].
```

> The META directive allows simple
>   metadata items to be defined within a
>   template. These are evaluated when the
>   template is parsed and as such may
>   only contain simple values (e.g. it's
>   not possible to interpolate other
>   variables values into META variables).

```
[% META
   title   = 'The Cat in the Hat'
   author  = 'Dr. Seuss'
   version = 1.23 
%]
```

As you already mentioned in the question body, there's also this:
http://template-toolkit.org/docs/manual/Variables.html#section_Compile_Time_Constant_Folding

Comment: OK - the problem with the first two suggestions is that I want to maintain my constants in one place - my constants package.

The "Compile Time Constant Folding" suggestion seems the best solution - as i can use my constants package. But can someone explain how one would do this in a Catalyst controller?

Comment: For more details on Constants in TT have a look at: http://template-toolkit.org/docs/modules/Template/Namespace/Constants.html